# The memory use of the Swift Storage Node is too high

Tags: openstack-swift

I am testing the performance of Swift. The environment is composed of 1 Swift Proxy Node and 3 Swift Storage Nodes. Each of the storage nodes has the RAM of 2GB  and is mounted on a distribution of 100GB.

At first, the result of throughputs is acceptable. After several day's test, the performance is dropt a lot. And I find that the memory use of the Storage Nodes is very high (more than 95%).

Is there any configuration in Swift to control the memory use of the Node? Or is the only solution increasing the RAM (etc 8GB RAM)? Will the Node with 8GB RAM be out of memory either?

Answer (score 1):

I think the high memory usage is OK. Linux borrows much memory for disk caching. You can find more information [here](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/).

I also experienced the performance drop after I had uploaded a lot of files. I believe that it was because many daemons (replicators, updaters) were busy working.

Comment: I have considered the cache reason and tested the 'real used' by 'free' command. The proxy node is OK while the storage node is really used. According to your opinion, it doesn't mean 'memory leak', and is the only thing I should do to have a more powerful PC for storage node?

Comment: Maybe you could add more memory. My storage nodes eats almost 3g~4g ram. I gave them 8g though.